# Golang - Function with multiple input types

Tags: go

I'm brand new to go and can't figure out how to do something pretty basic. Let's say that I have the following two structs:

```
type FooStructOld struct {
    foo1, foo2, foo3 int
}

type FooStructNew struct {
    foo1, foo2 int
}
```

I then want to have a function that updates the input. For example for a single type:

```
func updateval(arg *FooStructOld) {
    arg.foo1 = 1
}
```

This works as expected. However I would like the function `updateval` to take either FooStructOld or FooStructNew as an input. I know that I should be using an interface type but I can't quite get it to work. For example, when I try the following:

I get this error:

```
arg.foo1 undefined (type interface {} is interface with no methods)
cannot assign interface {} to a (type *FooStructOld) in multiple assignment: need type assertion
```

Does anyone know a solution for this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can either use a type assertion to extract the value from an `interface{}`

```
func updateval(arg interface{}) {
    switch arg := arg.(type) {
    case *FooStructOld:
        arg.foo1 = 1
    case *FooStructNew:
        arg.foo1 = 1
    }
}
```

Or you could implement an interface that does the update

```
type FooUpdater interface {
    UpdateFoo()
}

type FooStructOld struct {
    foo1, foo2, foo3 int
}

func (f *FooStructOld) UpdateFoo() {
    f.foo1 = 1
}

type FooStructNew struct {
    foo1, foo2 int
}

func (f *FooStructNew) UpdateFoo() {
    f.foo1 = 1
}

func updateval(arg FooUpdater) {
    arg.UpdateFoo()
}
```

Comment: I'm getting the following error when I try your first solution: `arg.foo1 undefined (type interface {} is interface with no methods)`

Comment: @user2694306: please show what you've tried. This works: https://play.golang.org/p/-wqJ9SPOwj